# Rounded corners in subtitle (Advanced Substation Alpha [.ass])

Tags: ffmpeg, background, border, rounded-corners, srt

Is it possible to have rounded corners with the BorderStyle 4 in .ass (Advanced Substation Alpha)?
I only found out that the BorderStyle 4 exists, because I was looking at [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870169/how-to-set-background-to-subtitle-in-ffmpeg/25880038#25880038). Is there any good and complete documentation of the Advanced Substation Alpha format?

I'm currently using the following configuration:

BorderStyle=4
Outline=10

[image: Preview of the current state]

Comment: I think the workaround would be just placing the pre-made or generated image in the place of subs. One should find a way to get coordinates for each set. It may be complicated, but I guess, I'll try to do something like this.