# Is there any way to change subtitle font in an mkv file in batches?

Tags: ffmpeg, fonts, subtitle

I have been using aegis subs till now but i need to do it in batches. Is there any way to do it in batch from ffmpeg or some cli?

Comment: Improved grammar.

Comment: First you should try to do one file with ffmpeg, Then, if that work put a loop around it.

Comment: Answer to "batch" question depends on your OS. Answer to ffmpeg question depends on your inputs: show complete output of `ffmpeg -i input.mkv`

Comment: you can try this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363334/how-to-add-font-size-in-subtitles-in-ffmpeg-video-filter