# How to embed subtitles to .mp4 movie using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitle, transcoding

I'm trying to embed subtitles I wrote to a movie I created.
I'm using FFmpeg version: `ffmpeg-20150418-git-edbb9b5-win64-static` with the command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -f srt -i subs.srt -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text out.mp4
```

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672809/use-ffmpeg-to-add-text-subtitles).

But I get errors during the process, and when the process is done there's an output file `out.mp4` without subtitles embedded.
When I play the `in.mp4` in some player such as `media player classic` with the subtitles separately, the subtitles are sync and everything is fine.

The subtitles are `subrip` encoded in `UTF8`.

I tried to look out for these errors but didn't find anything useful. it seems something ridiculous.
What am I doing wrong?

Errors such as:

```
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -8 / timestamp: 72205 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
```

Movie details from `Media info`:

```
Video  
ID: 1  
Format: AVC  
Format/Info: Advanced Video Codec  
Format profile: Main@L4.2  
Format settings, CABAC: Yes  
Format settings, ReFrames: 3 frames  
Format settings, GOP: M=4, N=24  
Codec ID: avc1  
Codec ID/Info: Advanced Video Coding  
Duration: 8mn 32s  
Source duration: 8mn 32s  
Bit rate: 23.4 Mbps  
Width: 1920 pixels  
Height: 1080 pixels  
Display aspect ratio: 16:9  
Original display aspect ratio: 2.2:1  
Frame rate mode: Variable  
Frame rate: 23.976 fps  
Minimum frame rate: 23.976 fps  
Maximum frame rate: 24.000 fps  
Standard: NTSC  
Color space: YUV  
Chroma subsampling: 4:2:0  
Bit depth: 8 bits  
Scan type: Progressive  
Bits/(Pixel*Frame): 0.472  
Stream size: 1.40 GiB (99%)  
Source stream size: 1.40 GiB (99%)  
Language: English  
Encoded date: UTC 2015-04-28 20:31:41  
Tagged date: UTC 2015-04-28 20:31:41  
mdhd_Duration: 512137
```

Ffmpeg command output:

```
ffmpeg version N-71497-gedbb9b5 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 22.101 / 54. 22.101
  libavcodec     56. 34.100 / 56. 34.100
  libavformat    56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 14.100 /  5. 14.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'in.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2015-04-28 20:31:41
  Duration: 00:08:32.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 23640 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 40:33 DAR 640:297], 23444 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 t
bc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-28 20:31:41
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-28 20:31:41
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
Input #1, srt, from 'subs.srt':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Subtitle: subrip
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.30.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 40:33 DAR 640:297], q=2-31, 23444 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k t
bc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-28 20:31:41
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-28 20:31:41
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:2: Subtitle: mov_text ([8][0][0][0] / 0x0008)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.34.100 mov_text
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:2 (subrip (srt) -> mov_text (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -8 / timestamp: 72205 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -7 / timestamp: 74217 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -8 / timestamp: 76267 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -4 / timestamp: 77872 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -7 / timestamp: 79260 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -1 / timestamp: 88987 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -60 / timestamp: 91489 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -4 / timestamp: 108080 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -1 / timestamp: 112974 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -8 / timestamp: 115528 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -9 / timestamp: 122758 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -6 / timestamp: 124862 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -12 / timestamp: 130307 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -140 / timestamp: 150079 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -144 / timestamp: 156606 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -245 / timestamp: 158916 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -6 / timestamp: 231587 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -1 / timestamp: 234743 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -9 / timestamp: 239406 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -6 / timestamp: 242670 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -4 / timestamp: 249833 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -9 / timestamp: 252669 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -6 / timestamp: 257713 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -2 / timestamp: 272866 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -152 / timestamp: 276417 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -3 / timestamp: 290209 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -6 / timestamp: 302825 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -6 / timestamp: 305466 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -3 / timestamp: 314151 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -8 / timestamp: 315957 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -1 / timestamp: 322568 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -164 / timestamp: 333373 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -3 / timestamp: 379341 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -5 / timestamp: 385070 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -7 / timestamp: 396166 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -7 / timestamp: 402007 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -4 / timestamp: 404571 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -2 / timestamp: 418218 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -5 / timestamp: 428136 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -5 / timestamp: 433347 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -4 / timestamp: 438939 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -7 / timestamp: 445657 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -6 / timestamp: 449039 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -6 / timestamp: 451870 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] Application provided duration: -5 / timestamp: 456582 is out of range for mov/mp4 format
[mp4 @ 00000000003fe020] pts has no value
frame=12279 fps=138 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1477815kB time=00:08:32.16 bitrate=23637.2kbits/s
video:1465658kB audio:11840kB subtitle:8kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.020907%
```

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo may be interesting to you...sorry I haven't tried it elsewise.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf subtitles=subs.srt out.mp4` doesn't work for me.. also with the combination of `-c:s mov_text`

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered a similar error. It turns out that my SRT file had a bogus subtitle:

```
212
00:16:00,042 --> 00:15:57,581
Kim ?
```

Basically, this shows that the subtitle ends before it begins, which is not allowed in timed text, the underlying format used by the mov_text codec. You may also encounter similar errors if you have subtitles that overlap, as that's also not allowed with timed text.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any tools that will automatically fix this, so you'll need to go into your srt file and clean these up by hand.

Comment: I use Subtitle Edit (Visit www.nikse.dk for the latest version) this will do all these checks for you and fix common issues.