# ffmpeg with ass: How can I set the effect on subtitle?

Tags: ffmpeg, srt

I want to add text to clips with some effects, just like fade in or out. I check this url (http://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/ssa.html) and have no found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use ffmpeg to add text subtitles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672809/use-ffmpeg-to-add-text-subtitles)

Comment: No, I want to show some special effect.

Comment: SSA specs are here: http://moodub.free.fr/video/ass-specs.doc

Comment: There is effect parameter in that doc, but, no more description.

Comment: @DienBell bottom page 9 of the doc, continued on page 10. There doesn't seem to be a fade effect.