# Redux: how to add subtitles to mp4 using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a tiny little example mp4 video (which unfortunately stack overflow won't allow me to embed directly inside my question).  Following the advice previously offered [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672809/use-ffmpeg-to-add-text-subtitles/17584272#17584272), I'd like to add a subtitle to the video, which will flash on the screen for 2 seconds, using an .srt file that looks like this:

```
1
00:00:02,000 --> 00:00:04,000
Test subtitle
```

As provided in the link above, I issue a command that looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -f srt -i small.srt -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text small_subtitles.mp4 >& err.log
```

And the `err.log` file looks like this:

```
ffmpeg version N-76950-g401c93d-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --as=yasm --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-version3 --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=qtkit --disable-indev=x11grab_xcb
  libavutil      55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
  libavcodec     57. 15.100 / 57. 15.100
  libavformat    57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 15.100 /  6. 15.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'small.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:10.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 23 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 188x112 [SAR 1:1 DAR 47:28], 17 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #1, srt, from 'small.srt':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #1:0: Subtitle: subrip
[mp4 @ 0x7f8492848000] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, mp4, to 'small_subtitles.mp4':
  Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf57.17.100
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 188x112 [SAR 1:1 DAR 47:28], q=2-31, 17 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 15360 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1: Subtitle: mov_text ([8][0][0][0] / 0x0008) (default)
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.15.100 mov_text
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (subrip (srt) -> mov_text (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  601 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      29kB time=00:00:09.96 bitrate=  24.0kbits/s    
video:21kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 39.561928%
```

The resulting output, `small_subtitles.mp4`, does not seem to have the expected subtitle present.

Furthermore, the error message,

```
[mp4 @ 0x7f8492848000] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
```

is highlighted in bold colors when I run this at the command line without capturing the `err.log` file (which makes me think it must be a significant message), although I am unable to reproduce that special print formatting easily here.

I've also tried [this method](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo), but with the .avi replaced by .mp4, and it seems to just fail silently--no obvious error message, but also no subtitle in the resulting video either.

Anybody have an idea how to fix this?  In particular, what does the business about global headers mean?

I'm working on OS X and am open to hearing answers that would use other open source tools as well.

Comment: In the case of the first command you may need to enable subtitle display and choose a subtitle track in the player (eg: VLC).

Comment: O.K., great, how do I do that?

Comment: What player are you using? In VLC right-click the video, Subtitle, Sub Track