# Merge subtitle to mkv with ffmpeg cause error

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I need to merge a subtitle to an mkv file. I used the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv input.srt -map 0 -map 1 -c copy output.mkv
```

But is does not work and causes the error below:

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Function not implemented
```

How could I resolve it?

Comment: Check the responses here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672809/use-ffmpeg-to-add-text-subtitles

Comment: Of course you need to show the **complete** console output from your command and not just a segment.