# How to view subtitles vtt when AirPlay a mp4 file?

Tags: javascript, html, ffmpeg, m3u8, airplay

Target is view html subtitles in vtt format in TV when AirPlay is running.

html code:

```
<video preload="metadata" x-webkit-airplay="allow" src="a.mp4">
    <track kind="subtitles" default="" src="en.vtt" srclang="en">
    <track kind="subtitles" src="de.vtt" srclang="de">
    <track kind="subtitles" src="es.vtt" srclang="es">
    <track kind="subtitles" src="fr.vtt" srclang="fr">
</video>
```

The problem is when AirPlay is enabled video and audio plays on TV, but no subtitles showed.

I tried to include vtt/srt subtitles into the mp4 metadata with ffmpeg and subtitles working with VLC but not working when AirPlay this files

```
ffmpeg -i 8499.mp4 -i 8499.en.vtt -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy -map 1 -c:s:0 mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=en 8499.en.mp4
ffmpeg -i 8499.mp4 -i 8499.en.srt -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy -map 1 -c:s:0 srt -metadata:s:s:0 language=en 8499.en.mp4
```

Also tried to send a .m3u8 with no luck. Any of you know how is the basic format for a simple .m3u8 with a .mp4 and .vtt working when AirPlay?

Which is the standard subtitles solution for AirPlay?

Comment: Yes, into TV reciever I set subtitles ON.

Comment: It seems like there are generally a lot of problems with AirPlay and subtitles. Did you check this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8384173?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not surprised that iOS doesn't Airplay the VTT subtitles from `<video>` to an Airplay sink.

iOS (and probably tvOS as well) only supports 1 embedded subtitle/captioning format: [MP4 Timed Text / MPEG-4 Part 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_17). Sometimes it is called Quicktime Timed Text. Safari also supports VTT (but not SRT) for `<video>`, but that is only in Safari.

One of your `ffmpeg` examples is close. If you want to Airplay MP4 files with subtitles/captions you must start with an `SRT` subtitle file as the input. Not an MP4 Timed Text file (which are far less common than `SRT`). Using `mov_text` will encode it.

This is an example I found in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17584272/1152664) relating to this question.

`ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -i infile.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text outfile.mp4`

Note: the order of `-c` commands matters if you use `-c copy`. You must specify any source stream changes after it

Comment: From https://ffmpeg.org/general.html#toc-Subtitle-Formats  "3GPP Timed Text" ffmpeg not support muxing, demuxing for this format.

Comment: I didn't realize that. I've only muxed MP4TT once and it was a long time ago. I might have used mp4box. It appears that the best way to do it is to use an `srt` file as the subtitle input and use the `mov_text` command. I'm updating my answer, and adding a link to another answer.