# How can I display subtitles along with a video with Streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit, caption, closed-captions, video-subtitles

I use [Streamlit](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit) to demonstrate some speech recognition system. How can I display subtitles along with a video with Streamlit?

[st.video](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/media/st.video) [doesn't](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/1662) seem to have this option. What are some workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's [not supported by `streamlit`](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/1662). As a workaround you can [use `ffmpeg` to add subtitles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672809/use-ffmpeg-to-add-text-subtitles) to video and display that video.